# Check if utf8 conversion needed and convert to utf8

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I need to read files received from server line by line, check if utf8 conversion is needed on the data, if needed convert it to utf8 and pass on.

How can I check if utf8 conversion is needed?

For converting to utf8, i can use toUTF8String from icu library.
Does toUTF8String  internally checks if input is already in UTF8?

Comment: This will be hard to do, I think. Doesn't the server already know what format its data is in? What is it if it's not UTF8 - 7-bit ASCII? 8-bit ASCII with a code page (ANSI)? Something else?

Comment: Check [**uchardet**](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/uchardet).

Comment: Checking if a stream of bytes is encoded with UTF-8 is [perfectly](https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/guess_encoding.html) [feasible](https://lemire.me/blog/2018/05/09/how-quickly-can-you-check-that-a-string-is-valid-unicode-utf-8/) However, if you don't know in which encoding the data is coming in (other than UTF-8), then converting it blindly to UTF-8 is asking for trouble.

Comment: @gustgr Well, you can check it it's not UTF-8 or check if it's probabilistically UFT-8, but not If it _is_.

Comment: @TomBlodget in case of corrupted or truncated stream I understand what you are saying. But assuming one gets full non-corrupted sequences of 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes representing encoded code points, one can determine if they are valid UTF-8, right? I guess this doesn't necessarily mean it is really UTF-8, but something that quacks like UTF-8. Is this why you said "probabilistically"?

Answer (score 0):

```
#

# convert a file from UTF-16 to UTF-8 if it is UTF-16

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo Usage: 'utf16-to-utf8 <file>'
  exit 0
fi
if [ `uchardet $1` != 'UTF-16' ]; then
  echo $1 is not UTF-16
  exit 0
fi
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 $1  |sed '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' >$$
mv $$ $1
```